# Is it safe to use C# global variables in a background worker thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, backgroundworker

Hi
I am working on a simple desktop application, it needs to handle some operations like loading a webpage which may block the main thread, so i moved the code to a background worker.

My problem is there is a heavy class named UCSProject, which contains many string and List fields, i need to pass an instance of this class to the background worker, since the class is a bit heavy, i would like to reduce the number of duplicate instances by using the global variable directly, instead of passing it as an argument to the background worker.

To make it short, I just want to know is it safe to access global variables from a background worker thread in C#

Comment: It sounds like (perhaps) your UCSProject class should be broken down somehow, without having a great insight into the contents of it etc, perhaps some refactoring would be more beneficial? It sounds to me, like the wrong questions, maybe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is safe unless until both your threads(background & normal) not modifying the object.

If you want your object to be modified by each other, use [Lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I don't have the intention to change any values in the class, Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

By your question I suspect that you do not understand how variables to classes work. You do not need a global variable to only have one copy of your object. All variables will point on exactly the same object unless you `Clone` it or create a new one with the old one as prototype.

A global variable will in other words change nothing unless you explicitly create new copies as described in the previous paragraph.

I do also wonder how heavy your class can be if you think that the performance would be hurt by creating copies of it? How many mb do it weight?

**Update**

This article series describes in great detail what the heap and stack is: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/rmcochran/csharp_memory01122006130034pm/csharp_memory.aspx

Comment: I can't give an exact number on the weight because, it contains a few List<string> fields whose values are assigned based on the user input, which may run into a few KB, but it won't be anything sort of in the MB range. Even if it is in bits, i don't think duplicate values are advisable in a application

Comment: Nothing will be duplicated as long as you just pass the variable as method argument or do assignments like `UCSProject proj = originalProjVar;`

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but doesn't the reference types require some holding value (like some pointer or something) to reference to them.I mean if we pass a reference type as an argument, it got to send something at least the reference, which is a duplicate

Comment: There will of course be multiple references (let's say pointers). But the same object will be changed and multiple pointers to not affect performance.

Answer (score 1):

It is safe, but you have to synchronize access to the variables, e.g. by using the `lock` statement.

See "[lock Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)" in the MSDN library.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not, unless you're locking it with `lock(object) { }` whenever you use any of its data fields.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not modifying any of the strings or variables then you don't need to lock.

I'd also consider making this a static class *if* the data is shared across the whole application -- then you won't need to pass an instance.

If you need modify or update the data -- use [Lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You may also use `[ThreadStatic]`. The value of the variable will be unique for each thread. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for how to use it.