# Cancel background worker, update db and mail

Tags: vb.net, exception, backgroundworker

I'm working on a program that uses a background worker and I'm trying to get my cancellation to work. When cancelling out of the program, I want it to update my database (put it in a log that the operation was cancelled) and send an email out with the status.

I have the following code in my program:
(At the top of the background worker)

```
If bworker.CancellationPending Then
    e.Cancel = True
    Exit Do
End If
```

Which works and gets me to the bgworker_RunWorkerCompleted part of the script. But from there it falls apart. I'm getting a lot of exceptions and they are either as simple as "Operation was cancelled" or an error where it's trying to call a disposed object when it's not supposed to.

Here is the code for the RunWorkerCompleted:

```
Private Sub bgworker_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bgworker.RunWorkerCompleted
    StopTimer()

    If e.Cancelled Then
        Call UpdateDB(e.Result(0), e.Result(1), e.Result(5), e.Result(2), e.Result(3), "Cancelled")
        MessageBox.Show("Got Here - Cancelled")
        CloseMe()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Got Here - Complete")
        Call UpdateDB(e.Result(0), e.Result(1), e.Result(5), e.Result(2), e.Result(3), e.Result(7))
        CloseMe()
    End If
End Sub
```

CloseMe() just closes the window, removes a tray icon, and decides whether to fully close the program or just go back to the main menu. When I cancelled out of the program and I did not have the first MessageBox.Show (inside of the cancel portion), I was seeing the message box inside of the Complete/non-canceled code area. Once I put in the MessageBox.Show in the cancelled area, I started getting the generic "Operation has been cancelled" exception.

Any ideas on how I can finish this up so that the operation can be cancelled while allowing it to alert me that it was cancelled and not throw the exception?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.runworkercompletedeventargs.result.aspx):

> Your RunWorkerCompleted event handler should always check the Error
>   and Cancelled properties before accessing the Result property. If an
>   exception was raised or **if the operation was canceled, accessing the
>   Result property raises an exception.**

(emphasis mine)

I don't know what's in your `Result` object, but is there another way you can signal the values back for logging?
One option would be to *not* set the `Cancel` property, but instead store something in your `Result` object to indicate the cancel state.  In other words, act as if the operation succeeded, in your result store a flag that indicates that the cancellation occurred.

Comment: Thanks Geoff, your answer got me on the right path. What I wound up doing was declaring an array called results globally (i was already using it in the background worker) and then setting all of my results in there. Once I got to the runworkercompleted, if it was being cancelled I just referenced that array instead of e.Result and now everything is working fine

Comment: Remember to use `Lock` if you need to modify the global array; see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4517075/55487)